# Silent failure on move_uploaded_file and ZipArchive::Close

Tags: php, iis-7, uploadify

**UPDATE/POSSIBLE SOLUTION:** I've realized that the files are being moved from the `C:\Windows\Temp` but they are invisible due to file permissions. If I try to access the files via a browser, I get a 401 error. I believe that these files are retaining their original permissions and so I am unable to see them or mess with them via PHP/browser. The only option is to change the `C:\Windows\Temp` folder permissions or move the default_upload_folder to something within the `wwwroot` chain.

--

I have an IIS7 Server Running a PHP Script that accepts `$_FILES`, does a `move_uploaded_file` to add the files to a directory and also ZIPs the files together using `ZipArchive`.

Both of these statements are failing.

Here is the code logic:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);

if(!empty($_FILES)){

   $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
   $targetPath = 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\sitename\\design\\uploads\\';
   $targetFile = $targetPath.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

   $zip_file = $targetPath . htmlspecialchars($_POST['session_id']) . '.zip';

   move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);

   $zip = new ZipArchive;
   $res = $zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);
   $zip->addFile($tempFile, $_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
   $zip->close();

}
```

`$tempFile` and `$targetPath` show as having `0777` permissions when I check them from within the script.

`move_uploaded_file` shows no error and returns `true`, but errors if I use a different directory. It appears this directory is correct. This code fails to move the file into the new directory. There is no error message if I use a `try...catch`.

None of the `ZipArchive` code fails until `$zip->close()`, which returns `false`. There is no error message if I use a `try...catch`.

The code worked perfectly on my WAMP test environment. The code running this script is `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitename\design\uploadify\uploadify.php`.

`$_FILES` has correct data based on the `var_dump`. `$tempFile` resolves to `C:\Windows\Temp\php___.tmp`. I have a feeling that this may be where my issue lies, but I don't know how to address it.

Comment: What is the value of $_FILES['Filedata']['error']?  It should be UPLOAD_ERR_OK (0).

Comment: Example $_FILES would be: Array
(
    [Filedata] => Array
        (
            [name] => vbv_logo.gif
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\phpC62F.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 2132
        )

)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have your `doc_root` setting in php.ini poinitng to proper directory. You should also specify `upload_tmp_dir` (in `File uploads` section; subfolder of `doc_root` would be awesome) to make sure it is different than system default.